# CodeIgniter 4 Nested Comments with CSRF Protection

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, csrf, codeigniter-4

I am working on a comment section for viewed images with nested replies using JQuery and AJAX. I have the actual comment posting working, however, I can only submit one comment due to regenerating CSRF token issues.

I implemented CSRF functionality on a few other functions in the same script and they work fine. To regenerate the new tokens I just included new calls to `csrf_token()` and `csrf_hash()` in a json object that was returned upon AJAX success. With this AJAX call, html is returned so I can't use the same method.

I'm very new to AJAX and JQUERY so I hope it's not a stupid mistake..,.

I am using this example from [Roy Tutorials](https://roytuts.com/codeigniter-4-mysql-ajax-nested-comment-system/). I will try to keep the code dumping to a minimum as it is verbose.

Here is my `view_image.js` script (excerpt only showing comment related functions):

```
        $("#cancel-comment-reply-link").hide();

        $(".reply-button").on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).attr("id");

            if ($("#li-comment-" + id).find('ul').length > 0) {
                $("#li-comment-" + id + " ul:first").prepend($("#comment-form-wrapper"));
            } else {
                $("#li-comment-" + id).append($("#comment-form-wrapper"));
            }

            $("#reply-id").attr("value", id);
            $("#cancel-comment-reply-link").show();
        });

        $("#cancel-comment-reply-link").bind("click", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#reply-id").attr("value", "");
            $("#comment-object").prepend($("#comment-form-wrapper"));
            $(this).hide();
        });

        $("#comment-form").bind("submit", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            if ($("#comment-text").val() == "") {
                alert("Please enter your comment");
                return false;
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "<?= base_url('/images/view_image/addComment'); ?>",
                data: $('#comment-form').serialize() + "&" + [csrfName] + "=" + csrfHash,
                dataType: 'html',
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('#comment-object').block({
                        message: "Please wait...",
                        css: {
                            border: 'none',
                            padding: '15px',
                            backgroundColor: '#ccc',
                            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
                            '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
                        },
                        overlayCSS: {
                            backgroundColor: '#ffe'
                        },
                    });
                },
                success: function (comment) {
                    var replyID = $("#reply-id").val();

                    if (replyID == "") {
                        $("#comment-object ul:first").prepend(comment);

                        if (comment.toLowerCase().indexOf("error") >= 0) {
                            $("#comment-resp-err").attr("value", comment);
                        }
                    } else {

                        if ($("#li-comment-" + replyID).find('ul').length > 0) {
                            $("#li-comment-" + replyID).append('<ul class="comment-text">' + comment + '</ul>');
                        }
                    }
                    $("#comment-text").attr("value", "");
                    $("#reply-id").attr("value", "");
                    $("#cancel-comment-reply-link").hide();
                    $("#comment-object").prepend($("#comment-form-wrapper"));
                    $("#comment-object").unblock();
                }
            });
        });
```

Just for clarity's sake, here is an example of an Ajax request that successfully implements CSRF tokens.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
        var csrfName = "<?= csrf_token(); ?>";
        var csrfHash = "<?= csrf_hash(); ?>"; 

        // If user views image (on page refresh)
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "<?= base_url('/images/view_image/action'); ?>",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                [csrfName]: csrfHash,
                "viewkey": viewkey,
                "action": 'view',
            },
            headers: {
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var res = data;
                csrfName = data.csrfName;
                csrfHash = data.csrfHash;

                // display number of views
                $('span.views').text(res.views);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Is that correct JavaScript syntax `[csrfName]: csrfHash,` ?

Comment: It works. Without the square brackets the CSRF name doesn't populate from the .ENV file.

Comment: How about `"<?= csrf_token(); ?>": "<?= csrf_hash(); ?>",` instead?